# 1394661620440271000/1000000: No such file or directory

Tags: shell, date, milliseconds, elapsedtime

I am running this command in my shell script to get time in milliseconds:

```
    START=`$(date +%s%N)/1000000`
```

However I keep getting the error:

```
   1394661620440271000/1000000: No such file or directory
```

I tried to change the code by adding brackets, extra dollar signs, but I keep getting different kinds of errors. How can I fix the code? Could anyone help with that?

Comment: change the backticks to double quotes.  You'll also need to use some kind of evaluator to do the division.

Comment: Backticks mean "execute the stuff inside as a command".  `1394661620440271000/1000000` doesn't mean "do division", it means "execute the `1394661620440271000/1000000` file".

Comment: fastest route to understanding errors like this is to turn on shell debug/trace feature with `set -vx` and turn it back off with `set +vx`. Wrap your problem line with those, and you'll at least be asking a new level of question. try `ST=$(( $(date +%s%N) / 1000000))` . Good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

assuming that you're using bash:

```
START=$(( $(date '+%s%N') / 1000000 ))
```

you can't just say / on the command line to divide numbers. (( ... )) does arithmetic evaluation in bash.

Comment: Come on, you ninjad me by 12 seconds... Too bad. You also have an explination, so +1.

Comment: is there a way to get a dot between seconds and milliseconds? e.g. if it is 14160 in milliseconds, i'd get an output of 14.160?

Comment: there is if you use glenn jackman's method: use date +%s.%N then chop off the last six characters.

Comment: `$(( ... ))` is part of the POSIX specification, not a `bash`ism.

Answer (score 2):

I think you want the following:

```
START=$(($(date +%s%N)/1000000))
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also use plain string manipulation:

```
$ start=$(date '+%s%N')
$ echo $start
1394663274979099354
$ echo ${start:0:-6}
1394663274979
```

Answer (score 0):

The `printf` statement can round a value to the nearest millisecond:

```
printf "%0.3f\n" $(date +%s.%N)
```